# Once variable is assigned a value do not let it be overwritten

Tags: excel, vba

I have a global variable `ErrorMsg` that can be set based on multiple different functions. The problem I am running into is if a certain condition is met, then the macro will assign `ErrorMsg` a text string that will be displayed in the worksheet `Log Sheet`. The way I have my code set up, even if an error occurs and `ErrorMsg` has a set text string assigned to it, the macro will continue running all the way through all the data until it is at the end. The issue with this that a lot of the conditions stem off each other. So if the function `GetColumnIndex` throws an error, assigns `ErrorMsg` a text string and continues on, then the next function like `GetData` will also throw an error and overwrite the value of `ErrorMsg` to be whatever it is set within its function. This occurs because the value that comes from `GetColumnIndex` is an input in `GetData` function. So my question is, how do I tell the macro to recognize once a value has been set to `ErrorMsg` to continue running through the code, but to not overwrite the variable with an updated text string. As you can see in the script, each function has a line that defines what `ErrorMsg` is. I am looking to find a way for if `GetColumnIndex` set `ErrorMsg` to be the text string to not have `GetData` overwrite `ErrorMsg` to a different text string.

Here are the functions I mentioned above.

```
Global ErrorMsg As String 
Sub Main 
Dim cell As Range, ws As Worksheet, sysnum As String, sysrow As Integer, wb As Workbook, logsht As Worksheet 
Dim power_col As Long, power_value As Double 

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook 
Set ws = ActiveWorksheet 
Set logsht = wb.Worksheets("Log Sheet") 

For Each cell In ws.Range("E2", ws.cells(ws.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp)).cells 
sysnum = cell.Value
sysrow = cell.row

power_col = GetColumnIndex(ws, "Power (mW)")
power_value = GetJiraData(ws, sysrow, power_col)

Dim begincell As Long
With logsht 
    begincell = .cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    .cells(begincell + 1, 2).Value = sysnum
    .cells(begincell + 1, 2).Font.Bold = True
    If Not ErrorMsg = "" Then
        .cells(begincell + 1, 3).Value = "Complete with Erorr - " & ErrorMsg
        .cells(begincell + 1, 3).Font.Bold = True
        .cells(begincell + 1, 3).Interior.Color = vbRed
    Else
        .cells(begincell + 1, 3).Value = "Completed without Errors"
        .cells(begincell + 1, 3).Font.Bold = True
        .cells(begincell + 1, 3).Interior.Color = vbGreen
    End If
End With

Next cell 

End Sub
```

---

```
Function GetColumnIndex(sht As Worksheet, colname As String) As Double 
Dim paramname As Range
Set paramname = sht.Range("A1", sht.cells(2, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).cells.Find(What:=colname, Lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas, searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=True) 
    If Not paramname Is Nothing Then 
        GetColumnIndex = paramname.Column
    ElseIf paramname Is Nothing Then 
       ErrorMsg = colname & " column index could not be found. Check before running again."
    End If
End Function
```

---

```
Function GetData(sht As Worksheet, WDrow As Integer, parametercol As Long) 
GetData = sht.cells(WDrow, parametercol)
If GetData = -999 Then
ElseIf GetData < 0 Then
    ErrorMsg = "Data cannot be a negative number. Check before running again." 
End If
End Function
```

Comment: `If ErrorMsg = "" Then ErrorMsg = "your message"` would be one option.

Comment: @BrianMStafford if `ErrorMsg` is empty then it will be `cells(lastrow + 1, 3).Value = "Completed without Errors"
                .cells(lastrow + 1, 3).Font.Bold = True
                .cells(lastrow + 1, 3).Interior.Color = vbGreen` described in the `Else` portion

Comment: Why not have your functions like `GetColumnIndex` or `GetData` return an error value if there's a problem?  Then you can check the return value from each before proceeding with the next.

Comment: Side note, `Global` means exactly the same thing as `Public` in VBA: there is no reason to make anything `Global`.

Comment: @TimWilliams If an error occurs it set `ErrorMsg` to be the specific string.

Comment: I can see that, but you don't check for an error after each call where `ErrorMsg` might get set - that's just allowing errors to accumulate, and makes it harder to know which parts of your code were successful or not, so you can take the appropriate action.

Comment: @TimWilliams Ok, how would you suggest I do that then? Have it say `ElseIf ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg then continue`?

Comment: You have a bad design for handling errors.   Rather than trying to bad design work, change the design

Comment: @chrisneilsen do you have any recommendations on how I should be handling errors then?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```vb
If lenb(ErrorMsg) > 0 then ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg & vbCrLf`
ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg  & "your text"
```

And when you have written the error message to the sheet, clear `ErrorMsg`:`

```vb
ErrorMsg = vbNullString
```

Comment: Can you explain what lenb is? And does this then set `ErrorMsg` to be the first text string it was assigned? Also wouldn't it need to be `ErrorMsg >= 1` since if it is only set to 1 then there will be no issue with overwritting?

Comment: UPDATE: I have tried your suggestion, however, `ErrorMsg` is still being overwritten and only displays the most recent `ErrorMsg` text string rather than the first assigned one.

Comment: @resu_student `LenB` is a VBA standard library function that returns the byte length of a value - you can use it like here to get the byte length of a string, but it can also give you the byte length of a user-defined type (UDT) or of a pointer (useful in x86/x64 scenarios).

Comment: I posit that the premise is flawed; have you considered storing the messages in a collection instead of a string? You can then easily retrieve the first message at index 1, concatenate them into a single message, know that all went well when the Count is 0, ...also consider using appropriate error handling (`On Error...`) and raising actual errors (`Err.Raise`) with custom messages, so you could simplify your code to focus on the _happy path_ rather than having if/elseif everywhere.